# Get all records with the same Name value column - LINQ

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, linq

I have a **WindowsForms** application. In this form I need to show the user the
table depends on his data input. 
I have a **Children** table and a button.. when the user clicks on that button I show
him a pop up window to let him enter the child name.. now in my table I have some 
records with the same child name.. and when the user enter for example 'john' as a child's name, I want to show him all the children records with the same name..

I tried this code :

```
var query = db.ChildrenTbl.Where(c => c.ChildName.ToLower().Contains(childName));
```

and this code :

```
    var query = from child in db.ChildrenTbl
                where child.ChildName.ToLower().Contains(childName)
                select child;
```

but both of theme give just one record and not the all records with the same child's name..
what is wrong?

Comment: can you post some example data from the db? it's probably just an upper/lower-casing issue

Comment: Have you tried: `var query = db.ChildrenTbl.Where(c => c.ChildName.ToLower().Contains(childName.ToLower()));`

Comment: @MikeCorcoran I forgot to write to **ToLower()** method in my post.. 
so I edited my question and now the code I gave looks as I wrote in my application.. and one more thing.. it's not the case because Im converting the given input from the user to lower letters

Comment: @Elior looks like you have just one recored which contains child name

Comment: @lazyberezovsky no.. I inserted to records manually.. i'll try to create this table one more time.. and see if it'll help

Comment: I would advise setting a break when you do get your query and looking at ChildrenTbl to see what it contains.  Then you will be able to see if it is a problem with the content and what the problem might be.

Comment: Post db schema for tables in question?

Comment: its ok i fixed it.. i created the table once again and changed the 'Contains()' to 'Equals()'

Comment: Changing "Contains()" to "Equals()" would work if the search you are trying to execute is an exact matching search. However, it won't work similar to an SQL "Like" statement i.e. searching for "john" won't give you both "john" and "johnson". If you want to do something like that and the "Contains" method does not work, you can try using the "String.IndexOf" method. You can have Where (c => c.ChildName.ToLower().IndexOf(childName.ToLower().Trim()) != -1). This condition should return all strings that contain the name you entered.